# Amazon AWS getAttribute() using AWS.config.credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have just started with Amazon Cognito and I want to use it for my web application. I want to develop a stateless app, in which I SignUp/SignIn using Cognito and then using the JWT token in rest of the requests.

I have implemented sign-up and sign-in flow in Node.js using `amazon-cognito-identity-js` package and then using the JWT token to call a lambda function using `aws-sdk`. Things are as expected till here.

But now the issue is with different user operations like `get attribute`, `verify attribute`, `update password` etc. as listed @ 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html

All of these operations require `cognitoUser` object and in the documentation they are using `userPool.getCurrentUser();` expression.

And I have read somewhere that this method returns the last authenticated user. So I think this expression `userPool.getCurrentUser();` will cause conflicts. For example if UserB logs in after UserA and UserA tries to update his password, it will not work.

Can someone suggests me what are the possible solutions?

1. Should I store the `cognitoUser` object in session at server side ?
   [This solution breaks my stateless requirement and I will have to maintain session on server side.]
2. Is there any way to perform these operations using JWT token ?

Please suggest if you can think of any other better approach to implement Cognito in web app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a stateless app using cognito and lambdas.

The way we have set it up is to not call lambdas directly but to use Api Gateway and lambda-proxy integration.

If you call lambdas directly from your front end code and are using the cognito tokens for authentication then you need to put a lot of logic in each lambda to validate the token, e.g. download the relevant keys, check the signature of the jwt, timestamps, issuer etc. If you use API gateway then you can just [create a cognito authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html) and place it in front of your lambdas.

We pass the id_token when making api calls, then the call is validated by the authorizer and the lambda receives all the current attributes set up in the user pool. This means we don't need to make additional calls to get attributes.

For changing the user passwords this can be done from the front-end of the app by calling the [cognito api with the access_token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ChangePassword.html) if you have allowed it in the user pool client setup.

Comment: Thanks @Ravenscar , I will try the authorizer. Can you tell me how you are handling the token refresh ?
I suppose the API gateway will return `UnAuthorized` if the id_token is expired.

Also for calling cognito api with access_token, what would be the URL to call to ?

Comment: @Vicky the token refresh it's not good news, I have opened a github issue about six months ago here: https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js/issues/92 As for calling it with the access_token we've used the api linked above via the aws-sdk but using the access_token instead of configuring IAM.

Comment: Thanks @Ravenscar. You were very helpful.